# How to solve this MySQL query in php page?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to MYSQL. I have a data in a MYSQL database like this (example):

| S.no | Book Name | Date of Publication | Publication | ctags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 2021 | Oxford | Free,Video,Audio,Licensed |
| 2 | DEF | 2020 | Cambridge | Free,Video,Licensed, |
| 3 | GHI | 2019 | Bloomberry | Free,Audio,Licensed |
| 4 | JKL | 2018 | Penguin | Free, |
| 5 | MNO | 2017 | Jaya Prakash | Licensed |
| 6 | PQR | 2016 | Null | Free,Video,Audio |

There are multiple tag in the ctags column that are separated with comma. I shared above table only for simple example. In my MySQL database there is a column named as ctags and here I am sharing the original mysql query on php page.

The below code show all the information (s.no 1 to 6) in the page but I want to show those resource that are not ctags with licensed (s.no 4 and 6)

```
$qnew = "SELECT title, 
                location, 
                access_restrictions 
         FROM title t, location_title lt, location l 
         WHERE t.title_id = lt.title_id 
         AND l.location_id = lt.location_id 
         AND eres_display = 'Y' 
         order by t.title_id DESC limit 0,5";
```

The below code show nothing but I want to show those resource that are ctags with licensed (s.no 1, 2, 3 and 6).

```
$qnew = "SELECT title, 
                location, 
                access_restrictions 
         FROM title t, location_title lt, location l 
         WHERE t.title_id = lt.title_id AND l.location_id = lt.location_id 
         AND eres_display = 'Y' 
         AND ctags = 'Licensed' 
         order by t.title_id DESC limit 0,5";
```

What should I use to get the information from the MySQL database. Kindly help me to get this.

Comment: That sounds like bad database design - split the values  from `ctags`  up into a normalized database, such that such queries are easier to run

Comment: CSV isn't native a MySQL datatype. You can't query it like you could a column with [SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html) or [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html). Either convert to one of the above or normalize the ctags into a related table. Any of these will let you use indexes. A `LIKE %%` query won't use indexes, nor will [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) (which would be the "proper" dirty way of doing this).

Comment: Like Query take more time fetch data from database better you have fixed value "Licensed" use FIND_IN_SET.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing is using [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) , but keep in mind for larger tables it is a performance killer, you should normalize your data

```
CREATE TABLE t1  (
  S_no int,
  Book_Name varchar(5),
  Date_of_Publication int,
  Publication varchar(15),
  ctags varchar(255));

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
(1,'ABC',2021,'Oxford','Free,Video,Audio,Licensed'),
(2,'DEF',2020,'Cambridge','Free,Video,Licensed'),
(3,'GHI',2019,'Bloomberry','Free,Audio,Licensed'),
(4,'JKL',2018,'Penguin','Free'),
(5,'MNO',2017,'Jaya Prakash','Licensed'),
(6,'PQR',2016,'Null','Free,Video,Audio');
```

For Licensed only :

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE find_in_set('Licensed',ctags) >0;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a05dc51601077ae72718e537afa74a8)

For non Licensed only :

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE find_in_set('Licensed',ctags) <=0;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5938c61f0fc9a6185fd687f098527e01)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like operator to match Licensed in ctags col.

```
     $qnew = "SELECT title, 
            location, 
            access_restrictions 
     FROM title t, location_title lt, location l 
     WHERE t.title_id = lt.title_id 
     AND l.location_id = lt.location_id 
     AND eres_display = 'Y' 
     ctags NOT like  '%Licensed%'
     order by t.title_id DESC limit 0,5";
```

For licensed you can use something like this.

```
   $qnew = "SELECT title, 
            location, 
            access_restrictions 
     FROM title t, location_title lt, location l 
     WHERE t.title_id = lt.title_id AND l.location_id = lt.location_id 
     AND eres_display = 'Y' 
     AND ctags like '%Licensed%' 
     order by t.title_id DESC limit 0,5";
```

Comment: Thanks you so much it working.

Comment: what should I use for without licensed

Comment: use 1st query for without licensed and below query for licensed.

Comment: While this might work for your examples this would also select entries that have something like `Free,Unlicensed` or `LicensedForInternalUseOnly` as ctags. Read up on Database normalization

Comment: I used that query but it gives both licensed as well as without licensed. and I need to show only those who are not tag as licensed.. like s.no. 4 and 6.

Comment: Thank you both query is working.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Query

```
$qnew = "SELECT title, location, access_restrictions FROM title t, location_title lt, location l WHERE t.title_id = lt.title_id AND l.location_id =lt.location_id  AND eres_display = 'Y' AND FIND_IN_SET('Licensed', ctags)  order by t.title_id DESC limit 0,5";
```